# Interpretation and practical significance based on multiple linear regression coefficients

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, data-transformation, interaction, interpretation

I am having difficulty articulating the practical significance of positive and negative tone in job application cover letters for male and female job candidates. I obtained the following linear regression equation with all statistically significant coefficients.

Model lm:

```
Speed.Of.Obtaining.Job= 6.30 -0.76(EducationEngineering)
+ 0.04 (EducationManagement) - 0.18(Gender) 
- 0.02(Positive.Tone) - 0.06 (Negative.Tone) 
+ 0.03 (Gender:Positive.Tone) + 0.16 (Gender:Negative.Tone)
```

Transformations applied:

- `Speed.Of.Obtaining.Job = log(1/Days.To.Obtain.Job, base=10)`
- `Education`= Reference category is 'Arts'
- `Gender`= 1 (Female), 0 (Male)
- `Positive.Tone` = inverse hyperbolic sine transformation of percentage
  of positive words in a job cover letter
- `Negative.Tone` = inverse hyperbolic sine transformation of percentage of negative words in a job cover letter

How do I infer practical significance from the regression equation given the transformations? I am keen to make a statement like "for females/males, for every 1 percent increase in positive/negative words in their cover letter, the days to obtain job increases/decrease by _____".

Request your help.

Comment: What was the reason for those fancy transformations of `Tone` variables? Non-linear transforms mean that you can't make statements about linear effects on original scale ("for a unit change in words,...").

Comment: The transformations helped with residual normality.

Comment: If your goal is simple & interpretable effect sizes, I'd suggest dropping the transformation. While the significance measures _may_ become inflated, the effect sizes are much more robust (they remain BLUE without assuming any distribution).

Comment: @juod could you please clarify what you meant? I am not sure if I should live with non-normal residuals that results with non-transformed IVs

Comment: Hypothetically, if I were to not transform and IV, but only log transform the dependent variable (`Speed.Of.Obtaining.Job`) as above, how do I interpret the same coefficients for male/female?

Comment: as males are the reference group, a coefficient of -0.1 would mean "the IV is 0.1 lower for females". If the IV is log-transformed, it means that the log of IV is 0.1 smaller (or 10-fold smaller).